# SQL query against multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `pickles` with several hundred pickle types

Table `pickles` is structured with at least: `id, name, likes`

Starting with the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pickles 
WHERE likes > 100 
LIMIT 10
```

Let's say I need at LEAST 10 pickles to show to the user at any one time and let's say only 4 pickles are liked over 100 times. This means although there are several hundred available pickles only 4 will be pulled from this query.

How can I manipulate this query to pull up to 10 'over 100 liked' pickles and then if there are not 10 available then to fill the rest with random pickles?

Comment: SELECT * FROM pickles ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pick the pickles with the highest number of likes:

```
SELECT *
FROM pickles
ORDER BY likes DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

The `100` is rather irrelevant if you always want 10 rows returned.

Comment: This works, but I simplified (maybe too much so) my question. Although what you wrote works my real table doesn't have a 'likes' section but rather the 'likes' are calculated dynamically through searching through other tables so the idea is that once I have my top liked pickles I need a way to fill in the rest with arbitrary pickles afterwards

Comment: @Parad0x13 - You could `UNION` the results of Gordon's query with a random selection of pickles and then take the top 10; ensuring you don't include results in both sets, of course.

Comment: @Parad0x13 If you have different question, ask a different question, or amend your question above accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use order by likes and sort the selection result to descending order, this will give you a list of highest numbers of likes and then you can limit the records.

This should work :

```
     SELECT * FROM pickles ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT *
FROM pickles
WHERE likes > 100 OR id IN(SELECT id FROM pickles WHERE id > 1)
ORDER BY likes DESC
LIMIT 10;
```